# AJAX output to accordion panel

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following AJAX script:

```
<script>
$(function() {
$(".accButton").click()
var element = $(this);  
var id2 = element.attr("id");

$.ajax
(
 {
    type: "POST",
    url:"item_view.php",
    data: {id:id2},
    success: function(msg){
    $("#output_element").html(msg);
}});
});

</script>
```

and I need it to post the output to an accordion panel like this:

```
<div id="accordion">
<h3><a href="#">Header Name</a></h3>
<div id="output_element">
This is the content
</div>
```

The accordion is working as needed and my AJAX call is returning data as needed; I just can get it to show up in the 'output_element' div. Nothing is being displayed in the div.

Answer (score 0):

Try refresh() method. Find it here http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#method-refresh

```
$(function(){


    $("#accordion").accordion({ 
        active: 1,
        collapsible :true
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"item_view.php",
        data: {id:id2},
        success: function(msg){
            $("#output_element").html(msg);
            $("#accordion").accordion("refresh");
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Im getting a syntax error:  <script>$(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "refresh" )
      collapsible: true, active:false
    });
  });
  </script>

Comment: Put refresh at the end of your ajax call, not in the init of accordion. Refresh is something as 'update' so it tries to rebuild the accordion if something has changed

Comment: Im not sure where/how to add that to my AJAX function. Your link referenced the accordion widget info.

Comment: Thanks for the code; now the page loads fine and Im seeing data come through via the console, but the first row opens and then shuts when the page loads and all other rows open, but contain no content...any thoughts?